# differences: GADT, data family, data family that is a GADT

Tags: haskell, gadt

What/why are the differences between those three? Is a GADT (and regular data types) just a shorthand for a data family? Specifically what's the difference between:

```
data GADT a  where
  MkGADT :: Int -> GADT Int

data family FGADT a
data instance FGADT a  where             -- note not FGADT Int
  MkFGADT :: Int -> FGADT Int

data family DF a
data instance DF Int  where              -- using GADT syntax, but not a GADT
  MkDF :: Int -> DF Int
```

(Are those examples over-simplified, so I'm not seeing the subtleties of the differences?)

Data families are extensible, but GADTs are not. OTOH data family instances must not overlap. So I couldn't declare another instance/any other constructors for `FGADT`; just like I can't declare any other constructors for `GADT`. I can declare other instances for `DF`.

With pattern matching on those constructors, the rhs of the equation does 'know' that the payload is `Int`.

For class instances (I was surprised to find) I can write overlapping instances to consume GADTs:

```
instance C (GADT a) ...
instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} C (GADT Int) ...
```

and similarly for `(FGADT a), (FGADT Int)`. But not for `(DF a)`: it must be for `(DF Int)` -- that makes sense; there's no `data instance DF a`, and if there were it would overlap.

**ADDIT:** to clarify @kabuhr's answer (thank you)

> contrary to what I think you're claiming in part of your question, for a plain data family, matching on a constructor does not perform any inference

These types are tricky, so I expect I'd need explicit signatures to work with them. In that case the plain data family is easiest

```
inferDF (MkDF x) = x                 -- works without a signature
```

The inferred type `inferDF :: DF Int -> Int` makes sense. Giving it a signature `inferDF :: DF a -> a` doesn't make sense: there is no declaration for a `data instance DF a ...`. Similarly with `foodouble :: Foo Char a -> a` there is no `data instance Foo Char a ...`.

GADTs are awkward, I already know. So neither of these work without an explicit signature

```
inferGADT (MkGADT x) = x
inferFGADT (MkFGADT x) = x
```

Mysterious "untouchable" message, as you say. What I meant in my "matching on those constructors" comment was: the compiler 'knows' on rhs of an equation that the payload is `Int` (for all three constructors), so you'd better get any signatures consistent with that.

Then I'm thinking `data GADT a where ...` is as if `data instance GADT a where ...`. I can give a signature `inferGADT :: GADT a -> a` or `inferGADT :: GADT Int -> Int` (likewise for `inferFGADT`). That makes sense: there is a `data instance GADT a ...` or I can give a signature at a more specific type.

So in some ways data families are generalisations of GADTs. I also see as you say

> So, in some ways, GADTs are generalizations of data families.

Hmm. (The reason behind the question is that GHC Haskell has got to the stage of feature bloat: there's too many similar-but-different extensions. I was trying to prune it down to a smaller number of underlying abstractions. Then @HTNW's approach of explaining in terms of yet further extensions is opposite to what would help a learner. IMO existentials in data types should be chucked out: use GADTs instead. PatternSynonyms should be explained in terms of data types and mapping functions between them, not the other way round. Oh, and there's some DataKinds stuff, which I skipped over on first reading.)

Comment: A `data family` is not much more than a way to group together several newtype/data declarations. In fact, you can almost think of a data family as an injective open type family (where each `data instance` corresponds to a data decl and a `type instance` to that decl). That analogy breaks down in two places (that I can think of): data family type constructors can be partially applied and data family type constructors have stronger typing rules (`MyDataFamily a ~ g b` implies `MyDataFamily ~ g` and `a ~ b`, while `MyInjectiveTyFam a ~ MyInjectiveTyFam b` implies `a ~ b`).

Answer (score 6):

As a start, you should think of a data family as a collection of independent ADTs that happen to be indexed by a type, while a GADT is a single data type with an inferrable type parameter where constraints on that parameter (typically, equality constraints like `a ~ Int`) can be brought into scope by pattern matching.

This means that the biggest difference is that, contrary to what I think you're claiming in part of your question, for a plain data family, matching on a constructor does **not** perform any inference on the type parameter.  In particular, this typechecks:

```
inferGADT :: GADT a -> a
inferGADT (MkGADT n) = n
```

but this does *not*:

```
inferDF :: DF a -> a
inferDF (MkDF n) = n
```

and without type signatures, the first would fail to type check (with a mysterious "untouchable" message) while the second would be inferred as `DF Int -> Int`.

The situation becomes quite a bit more confusing for something like your `FGADT` type that combines data families with GADTs, and I confess I haven't really thought about how this works in detail.  But, as an interesting example, consider:

```
data family Foo a b
data instance Foo Int a where
  Bar :: Double -> Foo Int Double
  Baz :: String -> Foo Int String
data instance Foo Char Double where
  Quux :: Double -> Foo Char Double
data instance Foo Char String where
  Zlorf :: String -> Foo Char String
```

In this case, `Foo Int a` is a GADT with an inferrable `a` parameter:

```
fooint :: Foo Int a -> a
fooint (Bar x) = x + 1.0
fooint (Baz x) = x ++ "ish"
```

but `Foo Char a` is just a collection of separate ADTs, so this won't typecheck:

```
foodouble :: Foo Char a -> a
foodouble (Quux x) = x
```

for the same reason `inferDF` won't typecheck above.

Now, getting back to your plain `DF` and `GADT` types, you can largely emulate `DFs` just using `GADTs`.  For example, if you have a DF:

```
data family MyDF a
data instance MyDF Int where
  IntLit :: Int -> MyDF Int
  IntAdd :: MyDF Int -> MyDF Int -> MyDF Int
data instance MyDF Bool where
  Positive :: MyDF Int -> MyDF Bool
```

you can write it as a GADT just by writing separate blocks of constructors:

```
data MyGADT a where
  -- MyGADT Int
  IntLit' :: Int -> MyGADT Int
  IntAdd' :: MyGADT Int -> MyGADT Int -> MyGADT Int
  -- MyGADT Bool
  Positive' :: MyGADT Int -> MyGADT Bool
```

So, in some ways, GADTs are generalizations of data families.  However, a major use case for data families is defining associated data types for classes:

```
class MyClass a where
  data family MyRep a
instance MyClass Int where
  data instance MyRep Int = ...
instance MyClass String where
  data instance MyRep String = ...
```

where the "open" nature of data families is needed (and where the pattern-based inference methods of GADTs aren't helpful).

Comment: "you can largely emulate DFs just using GADTs" is I think misleading, because you could have a DF instance that's a newtype https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52417415/data-family-instances-newtype-data; emulating that as a GADT would block it from being a newtype. I'd rather say that a top-level GADT is like a DF with only one instance, in which the instance head is `DF a`.

Answer (score 4):

I think the difference becomes clear if we use `PatternSynonyms`-style type signatures for data constructors. Lets start with Haskell 98

```
data D a = D a a
```

You get a pattern type:

```
pattern D :: forall a. a -> a -> D a
```

it can be read in two directions. `D`, in "forward" or expression contexts, says, "`forall a`, you can give me 2 `a`s and I'll give you a `D a`". "Backwards", as a pattern, it says, "`forall a`, you can give me a `D a` and I'll give you 2 `a`s".

Now, the things you write in a GADT definition are not pattern types. What are they? Lies. Lies lies lies. Give them attention only insofar as the alternative is writing them out manually with `ExistentialQuantification`. Let's use this one

```
data GD a where
  GD :: Int -> GD Int
```

You get

```
--                      vv ignore
pattern GD :: forall a. () => (a ~ Int) => Int -> GD a
```

This says: `forall a`, you can give me a `GD a`, and I can give you a proof that `a ~ Int`, plus an `Int`.

Important observation: The return/match type of a GADT constructor is *always* the "data type head". I defined `data GD a where ...`; I got `GD :: forall a. ... GD a`. This is also true for Haskell 98 constructors, and also `data family` constructors, though it's a bit more subtle.

If I have a `GD a`, and I don't know what `a` is, I can pass into `GD` anyway, even though I wrote `GD :: Int -> GD Int`, which seems to say I can only match it with `GD Int`s. This is why I say GADT constructors lie. The pattern type never lies. It clearly states that, `forall a`, I can match a `GD a` with the `GD` constructor and get evidence for `a ~ Int` and a value of `Int`.

Ok, `data family`s. Lets not mix them with GADTs yet.

```
data Nat = Z | S Nat
data Vect (n :: Nat) (a :: Type) :: Type where
  VNil :: Vect Z a
  VCons :: a -> Vect n a -> Vect (S n) a -- try finding the pattern types for these btw

data family Rect (ns :: [Nat]) (a :: Type) :: Type
newtype instance Rect '[] a = RectNil a
newtype instance Rect (n : ns) a = RectCons (Vect n (Rect ns a))
```

There are actually *two* data type heads now. As @K.A.Buhr says, the different `data instance`s act like different data types that just *happen* to share a name. The pattern types are

```
pattern RectNil :: forall a. a -> Rect '[] a
pattern RectCons :: forall n ns a. Vect n (Rect ns a) -> Rect (n : ns) a
```

If I have a `Rect ns a`, and I don't know what `ns` is, *I cannot match on it*. `RectNil` only takes `Rect '[] a`s, `RectCons` only takes `Rect (n : ns) a`s. You might ask: "why would I want a reduction in power?" @KABuhr has given one: GADTs are closed (and for good reason; stay tuned), families are open. This doesn't hold in `Rect`'s case, as these instances already fill up the entire `[Nat] * Type` space. The reason is actually `newtype`.

Here's a GADT `RectG`:

```
data RectG :: [Nat] -> Type -> Type where
  RectGN :: a -> RectG '[] a
  RectGC :: Vect n (RectG ns a) -> RectG (n : ns) a
```

I get

```
-- it's fine if you don't get these
pattern RectGN :: forall ns a. () => (ns ~ '[]) => a -> RectG ns a
pattern RectGC :: forall ns' a. forall n ns. (ns' ~ (n : ns)) =>
                  Vect n (RectG ns a) -> RectG ns' a
-- just note that they both have the same matched type
-- which means there needs to be a runtime distinguishment
```

If I have a `RectG ns a` and don't know what `ns` is, I can still match on it just fine. The compiler has to preserve this information with a data constructor. So, if I had a `RectG [1000, 1000] Int`, I would incur an overhead of one million `RectGN` constructors that all "preserve" the same "information". `Rect [1000, 1000] Int` is fine, though, as I do not have the ability to match and tell whether a `Rect` is `RectNil` or `RectCons`. This allows the constructor to be `newtype`, as it holds no information. I would instead use a different GADT, somewhat like

```
data SingListNat :: [Nat] -> Type where
  SLNN :: SingListNat '[]
  SLNCZ :: SingListNat ns -> SingListNat (Z : ns)
  SLNCS :: SingListNat (n : ns) -> SingListNat (S n : ns)
```

that stores the dimensions of a `Rect` in `O(sum ns)` space instead of `O(product ns)` space (I think those are right). This is also why `GADT`s are closed and families are open. A GADT is just like a normal `data` type except it has equality evidence and existentials. It doesn't make sense to add constructors to a GADT any more than it makes sense to add constructors to a Haskell 98 type, because any code that doesn't know about one of the constructors is in for a *very* bad time. It's fine for families though, because, as you noticed, once you define a branch of a family, you cannot add more constructors in that branch. Once you know what branch you're in, you know the constructors, and no one can break that. You're not allowed to use any constructors if you don't know which branch to use.

Your examples don't really mix GADTs and data families. Pattern types are nifty in that they normalize away superficial differences in `data` definitions, so let's take a look.

```
data family FGADT a
data instance FGADT a where
  MkFGADT :: Int -> FGADT Int
```

Gives you

```
pattern MkFGADT :: forall a. () => (a ~ Int) => Int -> FGADT a
-- no different from a GADT; data family does nothing
```

But

```
data family DF a
data instance DF Int where
  MkDF :: Int -> DF Int
```

gives

```
pattern MkDF :: Int -> DF Int
-- GADT syntax did nothing
```

Here's a proper mixing

```
data family Map k :: Type -> Type
data instance Map Word8 :: Type -> Type where
  MW8BitSet :: BitSet8 -> Map Word8 Bool
  MW8General :: GeneralMap Word8 a -> Map Word8 a
```

Which gives patterns

```
pattern MW8BitSet :: forall a. () => (a ~ Bool) => BitSet8 -> Map Word8 a
pattern MW8General :: forall a. GeneralMap Word8 a -> Map Word8 a
```

If I have a `Map k v` and I don't know what `k` is, I can't match it against `MW8General` or `MW8BitSet`, because those only want `Map Word8`s. This is the `data family`'s influence. If I have a `Map Word8 v` and I don't know what `v` is, matching on the constructors *can* reveal to me whether it's known to be `Bool` or is something else.

Comment: This is very helpful!  I hope you don't mind, but I added a note about the `forall a. forall s. Num s=> ...` syntax corresponding to `() => Num s => ...`, as I'd never previously realized this and assume that I'm not the only one.

Comment: Why do you say lies?

Comment: Perhaps not outright falsehoods, but definitely lying by omission. GADT definition constructor types are only accurate when used as functions. If you don't consider the pattern types, `data D a where D :: Int -> D Int` and `data family D a; data instance D Int = D Int` seem like they should bahave similarly: `D :: Int -> D Int`. But this is misleading; the truth is `pattern D :: forall a. () => (a ~ Int) => Int -> D a` and `pattern D :: Int -> D Int` and those are not the same.

Comment: Downvoted: explaining 2 tricky concepts in terms of 2 more (pattern signatures and existential quant), and then another (singletons) is the opposite of helpful. I wish I'd not read your answer. I'm now more confused.

Comment: @AntC is this better?

Comment: Thank you for trying. I feel you're giving me a brain dump of everything you know about data decls. That's a Good Thing if others are getting insights: on SO there's not much on the topic; GHC's docos notoriously describe each extension separately, and are poor at explaining how they interact or interfere. For me, you seem to have answered a lot of questions I didn't ask and am not ready for. It would be a shame for this info to get buried/be difficult to search; I suggest you break it down into separate answers, and post on SO each question you think you're addressing and your answer.